# Syntax for Twilio Enqueue in C#

Tags: c#, twilio

I'm using Twilio Programmable Voice and my objective is to have a caller listen to on-hold music while waiting for an agent to take their call.

I believe the Enqueue method is the way to go since we manage our agents in a database and they may change (so Task Worker is not a good fit).  I'm clear on how to put callers in a Queue (see below).  But then, I need to dial out to a external number to get the agent on the phone who will take that call out of the queue and I cannot find the C# syntax on how to make that happen.

My plan is for each caller to be in their own uniquely identified queue.  But if that makes it more difficult I'm open to putting callers into the same queue I suppose.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var response = new TwilioResponse(); 
            response.Enqueue("Queue 23123412414124", new
            {
                action = Url.Action("LeaveQueue"),       //url to call when the call is dequeued
                waitUrl = Url.Action("WaitInQueue")    //url to call while the call waits
            });      
            return TwiML(response);
        }
```

Thanks!

[Update 1]
Here's what I put together in a TestController using ngrok to test locally.  I cannot quite tell if I'm getting a clean hangup or not but it does work!

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var response = new TwilioResponse();


            var Twil = new TwilioRestClient("TWILIO_SID", "TWILIO_PWD");
            Twil.InitiateOutboundCall(new CallOptions
            {
                To = "+17205551212",
                From = "+17205551212",
                Url = "http://701cfc2f.ngrok.io/Test/ContactAgent"
            });

            response.Enqueue("Demo Queue", new
            {
                action = Url.Action("LeaveQueue"),       //url to call when the call is dequeued
                waitUrl = Url.Action("WaitInQueue")    //url to call while the call waits
            });            

            return TwiML(response);
        }

        public ActionResult ContactAgent()
        {
            var response = new TwilioResponse();
            Twilio.TwiML.Queue q = new Twilio.TwiML.Queue("Demo Queue");
            response.Dial(q);
            return TwiML(response);
        }

        public ActionResult WaitInQueue(string CurrentQueueSize, string QueuePosition)
        {
            var response = new TwilioResponse();
            response.Say(string.Format("You are number {0} in the queue.  Please hold.", QueuePosition));
            response.Say("Play Background Music Here with Play Verb and loop it!");
            return TwiML(response);
        }

        public ActionResult LeaveQueue(string QueueSid)
        {
            var response = new TwilioResponse();
            var Twil = new TwilioRestClient("TWILIO_SID", "TWILIO_PWD");
            Twil.HangupCall(QueueSid, HangupStyle.Completed);

            return TwiML(response);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you know already based upon your snippet above that it would be much easier if your agent were connecting to the call.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/guides/queues#agent

If you need to play the wait music while you are calling the agent, you can use a combination of TwiML and the REST API. Please see the following example and [refer to syntax here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/blob/b3b136e2708444567628dfd3bbc4d98a3b6ec396/src/Twilio.Twiml.Tests/EnqueueTests.cs).

1) main.cs - you need to assign a URL to this file to your Twilio phone number. This functionality will enqueue the incoming call and then initiate a new call leg via Rest API to call your Agent and join both call legs into one conversation.

```
// Download the twilio-csharp library from twilio.com/docs/csharp/install
using System;
using Twilio;
class Example 
{
  static void Main(string[] args) 
  {
    // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account
    string AccountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    string AuthToken = "your_auth_token";
    var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

    var options = new CallOptions();
    options.Url = "http://URL/contactAgent.cs?queueid=NAME_YOUR_QUEUE";
    options.To = "+1415XXXXXXX"; // Agent phone 
    options.From = "+1415XXXXXXX";// Twilio phone 
    var call = twilio.InitiateOutboundCall(options);

    var response = new TwilioResponse();
    response.Enqueue("Queue 23123412414124", new { action="http://URL/terminate_childcall.php?childsid=YOUR_CALL_SID_IN_QUEUE_ID", waitURL="wait.xml"})

  }
}
```

---

2) contactAgent.cs - This file contains the equivalent TwiML which will be executed on your Agent's phone when an incoming call is accepted. It will then join both call legs into one conversation.

```
<Response>
    <Say>You will be connected to an incoming call</Say>
    <Dial><Queue>YOUR_QUEUE_ID</Queue></Dial>
```

3) terminate_childcall.cs - As the call leg initiated via Rest API is absolutely independent call leg, we need to terminate it when the customer who initiated an incoming call will be the 1st one who terminate the call.

```
  // Download the twilio-csharp library from twilio.com/docs/csharp/install
    using System;
    using Twilio;
    class Example 
    {
      static void Main(string[] args) 
      {
        // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account
        string AccountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        string AuthToken = "your_auth_token";
        var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

        // Get an object from its sid. If you do not have a sid,
       // check out the list resource examples on this page
       twilio.HangupCall("CALL_SID", HangupStyle.Completed);
      }
    }
```

Please do let me know if this helps.

Comment: I added an update to the question. Any thoughts on the clean hangup?